# why does windows have so many shells and command line interfaces?

Tags: windows, git, shell, powershell, command-line-interface

I have recently switched from MacOSX to Windows, and having had much experience using the OSX Terminal, I've been surprised by how many different CLI's there are in Windows. Specifically, it seems that in addition to cmd.exe and powershell, when I have installed some programs that require CLI usage, they create their own CLI's, i.e. git cmd, git bash, etc.

I'm used to working within one single app (terminal) for all of my projects/tasks, and switching between different CLI's for various tasks is proving annoying and confusing.

I'm not sure I'm asking the right question, so please let me know if you need a different one...: For those of you who have experience working at the command line in windows, is it 'normal' to keep switching between CLI's for different needs, or is it reasonable to get to a point with one CLI (i.e. powershell)? And if so, what should I be looking into?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: cmd is the old "dos" batch mechanism, powershell is the new batch mechanism. And they've added a [linux subsystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide), so you could have bash like you're used to on Mac.

Comment: I doubt that you *have* to use bash to use Git.  What does "git cmd" mean?  Is that just a shortcut that opens a cmd window?

Comment: ... everything you can do in cmd you should be able to do in Powershell, though I admit I haven't gotten around to learning it yet.  Most command-line tools should work from either, though they often offer a Bash shell instead just because they think it's better.

Answer (score 1):

Standard Cmd/Windows Command windows is basically your backwards compatible shell for Windows that will run everything specifically developed for it, including DOS batch files, etc.

Powershell is a supercharged, newer command window that allows scripting that is compatible with modern system administration for server environments in organizations, similar to vbscript or javascript.  Admins can run more compatible/modern scripting than the old DOS Batch files. It's really a new/separate scripting language, while still supporting most basic Windows Cmd window commands.

Git installs Git-cmd, which basically acts like a normal windows command terminal, and Git-Bash launches a unix-style Bash shell, because Git originated on Linux (and for Linux development..) and it's core operations expect a lot of core Linux commands, libraries and/or utilities.  So the Git-Bash is part of the standard install, giving you essentially a mini Linux install (or perhaps better phrasing would be a POSIX-compliant one?) and allows you to run a lot of tools/aliases/scripts developed for Git directly on Linux, and should be no different from a Linux Bash shell if you just happen to prefer that to Windows Cmd, with all basic command differences.

So I wouldn't say that there are "so many" different terminals.  Unix/Linux has many different flavors as well (C-shell, Bash, Ksh, etc.).  Powershell is rarely required for a regular user (per the comments, much more by developers), and Git Bash is unnecessary to run Git.

Isn't more options better - use what you like?  :)

Comment: its totally vice versa. who would use cmd in 2017? cmd is a joke. but regular users obviously do not use shells, but that's not what we are talking about here

Comment: "it's core operations actually run on a mini Linux install" is incorrect: GfW is a native Windows port which uses native Win32 API. Having said that, certain parts of Git indeed rely on POSIX shell scripting and expect certain command-line tools to be present (such as `sed` or `awk`). Some other parts are implemented in Perl (`git svn`), and some others --
 in Tcl/Tk (stock GUI tools). Still, this has nothing to do with Linux which is a POSIX-compatible *operating system kernel.*

Comment: @kostix Agreed with your points.  I'll update.

Comment: @4c74356b41 Mostly habit for me, though as I'm getting into Docker and other things, I am starting to default to Powershell...  Fair point though.